# What does this warning mean in corona sdk console?

Tags: coronasdk

I am getting the following warning in corona sdk console whenever i run my game

```
WARNING: Cannot create path for resource file 'level1.ccscene' b/c it doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.ccscene files are produced by Corona Composer GUI.  Your scene is expecting to load one of these scene files and can't find it.  If you're not using the Composer GUI, you probably can ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is commonly caused by trying to access a file that doesn't exist.

1. Double check that the file does exist
2. Make sure that you entered the file name correctly.

   a. Check for case sensivity (maybe the file is named "**L**evel1.ccscene"?)

   b. Check for typos in both the code and the file name.

Comment: I double checked everything & file exists & file names are correct too